java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class [class name] on path: [path] in Android Studio
My project has been cleaned and rebuilt successfully but when I try to run it, it simply crashes. The logcat says that there is a class not found exception. Here is the logcat:
2024-09-03 16:55:32.504 17287-17287 ziparchive              com.example.notesapp                 W  Unable to open '/data/data/com.example.notesapp/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes3.dm': No such file or directory
2024-09-03 16:55:32.507 17287-17287 ziparchive              com.example.notesapp                 W  Unable to open '/data/data/com.example.notesapp/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes4.dm': No such file or directory
2024-09-03 16:55:32.508 17287-17287 ziparchive              com.example.notesapp                 W  Unable to open '/data/data/com.example.notesapp/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes7.dm': No such file or directory
2024-09-03 16:55:32.509 17287-17287 ziparchive              com.example.notesapp                 W  Unable to open '/data/app/~~nBaq3G9tnkLwYlzJTvejaQ==/com.example.notesapp-jKEPMR3qxIq3DEXHowQGRg==/base.dm': No such file or directory
2024-09-03 16:55:32.509 17287-17287 ziparchive              com.example.notesapp                 W  Unable to open '/data/app/~~nBaq3G9tnkLwYlzJTvejaQ==/com.example.notesapp-jKEPMR3qxIq3DEXHowQGRg==/base.dm': No such file or directory
2024-09-03 16:55:33.285 17287-17287 nativeloader            com.example.notesapp                 D  Configuring clns-7 for other apk /data/app/~~nBaq3G9tnkLwYlzJTvejaQ==/com.example.notesapp-jKEPMR3qxIq3DEXHowQGRg==/base.apk. target_sdk_version=34, uses_libraries=, library_path=/data/app/~~nBaq3G9tnkLwYlzJTvejaQ==/com.example.notesapp-jKEPMR3qxIq3DEXHowQGRg==/lib/x86_64, permitted_path=/data:/mnt/expand:/data/user/0/com.example.notesapp
2024-09-03 16:55:33.310 17287-17287 GraphicsEnvironment     com.example.notesapp                 V  Currently set values for:
2024-09-03 16:55:33.310 17287-17287 GraphicsEnvironment     com.example.notesapp                 V    angle_gl_driver_selection_pkgs=[]
2024-09-03 16:55:33.310 17287-17287 GraphicsEnvironment     com.example.notesapp                 V    angle_gl_driver_selection_values=[]
2024-09-03 16:55:33.311 17287-17287 GraphicsEnvironment     com.example.notesapp                 V  Global.Settings values are invalid: number of packages: 0, number of values: 0
2024-09-03 16:55:33.311 17287-17287 GraphicsEnvironment     com.example.notesapp                 V  Neither updatable production driver nor prerelease driver is supported.
2024-09-03 16:55:33.325 17287-17287 AndroidRuntime          com.example.notesapp                 D  Shutting down VM
2024-09-03 16:55:33.331 17287-17287 AndroidRuntime          com.example.notesapp                 E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.example.notesapp, PID: 17287
                                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.example.notesapp.NoteApplication package com.example.notesapp: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.notesapp.NoteApplication" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.example.notesapp/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes3.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.notesapp/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes4.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.notesapp/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes7.dex", zip file "/data/app/~~nBaq3G9tnkLwYlzJTvejaQ==/com.example.notesapp-jKEPMR3qxIq3DEXHowQGRg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~nBaq3G9tnkLwYlzJTvejaQ==/com.example.notesapp-jKEPMR3qxIq3DEXHowQGRg==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
                                                                                                        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner(LoadedApk.java:1478)
                                                                                                        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner(LoadedApk.java:1403)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7464)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:232)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:317)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8705)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:580)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.notesapp.NoteApplication" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.example.notesapp/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes3.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.notesapp/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes4.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.notesapp/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes7.dex", zip file "/data/app/~~nBaq3G9tnkLwYlzJTvejaQ==/com.example.notesapp-jKEPMR3qxIq3DEXHowQGRg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~nBaq3G9tnkLwYlzJTvejaQ==/com.example.notesapp-jKEPMR3qxIq3DEXHowQGRg==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
                                                                                                        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:637)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
                                                                                                        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(AppComponentFactory.java:76)
                                                                                                        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(CoreComponentFactory.java:51)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1352)
                                                                                                        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner(LoadedApk.java:1471)
                                                                                                        ... 11 more
                                                                                                        Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/example/notesapp/Hilt_NoteApplication;
                                                                                                            at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
                                                                                                            at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:1276)
                                                                                                            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
                                                                                                            ... 16 more
                                                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.notesapp.Hilt_NoteApplication" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.example.notesapp/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes3.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.notesapp/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes4.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.notesapp/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes7.dex", zip file "/data/app/~~nBaq3G9tnkLwYlzJTvejaQ==/com.example.notesapp-jKEPMR3qxIq3DEXHowQGRg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~nBaq3G9tnkLwYlzJTvejaQ==/com.example.notesapp-jKEPMR3qxIq3DEXHowQGRg==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
                                                                                                            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
                                                                                                            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:637)
                                                                                                            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
                                                                                                            ... 19 more
2024-09-03 16:55:33.332 17287-17287 AndroidRuntime          com.example.notesapp                 E      Suppressed: [CIRCULAR REFERENCE: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/example/notesapp/Hilt_NoteApplication;]
2024-09-03 16:55:33.339 17287-17287 Process                 com.example.notesapp                 I  Sending signal. PID: 17287 SIG: 9


I am new to Android Studio and I am having a really hard time figuring this out. I tried googling for a solution but nothing has worked. I tried enabling multidex true (as suggested on another post on this website) but that didn't help either.
